# Правильно ли поставлены тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"...а вокруг — на полу, на полках, на небольшом диване — были рассажены десятки разномастных мягких игрушек".
Правильно ли тут расставлены тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово **вокруг** выступает в качестве обобщающего при однородных обстоятельствах места (на полу, на полках, на диване), поэтому после него нужно поставить двоеточие. Второе тире поставлено правильно: "...а вокруг: на полу, на полках, на небольшом диване — были рассажены десятки разномастных мягких игрушек".